# 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Text' could be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Oyunmekanikleriscript : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] int min;
   [SerializeField] int max;
   [SerializeField] int tahmin;
   [SerializeField] Text GuessTexti;
   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    OyununBaslangici();
    }

   public void OyununBaslangici()
   {
   max = max + 1;
   SonrakiTahmin();
   }

  public void arttir()
  {
    min = tahmin;
    SonrakiTahmin();
  }

  public void azalt()
  {
    max = tahmin;
    SonrakiTahmin();
  }

  public void SonrakiTahmin()
  {
    tahmin = (min + max) / 2;
    GuessTexti.Text = tahmin.ToString();
  }


}
```

Have unityengine.ui on top but I cant resolve it. It says that 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Text' could be found.
please help me

Comment: Is it suppose to be lowercase, e.g. `GuessTexti.text`? See the Unity docs here...[Text.text](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html)

Comment: I tried both of them but It didn’t work.

Comment: When i try with lowercase it says The type or namespace name 'text' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try fully qualifying the name of `Text`, see this Unity support response, [Type 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'text'](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1340078/type-text-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-text.html), basically change this `[SerializeField] Text GuessTexti;`... into this ... `[SerializeField] UnityEngine.UI.Text GuessTexti;`